# Problem with Vimeo Player Editor adaptive mode in Unity with AVPro player (ios)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vimeo

I am working with streaming video from vimeo to my unity app.
I bought the plugin avpro in unity asset store and download the plugin for unity of vimeo.
I founded that the plugin works very weel in android with adaptive mode with avpro. But when I switch to ios build the vimeo editor player does not show the dropdown to select avpro media player and neither the adaptive mode.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order for the community to help understand your exact issue, please post any relevant code.

Comment: Hi! Take a look at this article to help ask high-quality questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I solved . https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/74